# How to Force log out php session after x minutes (not inactive log out)

Tags: php, session, logout

The below code expires a page only on manual page refresh. I want the page to automatically expire the session and log out the user and redirect to the login page.

```
<?php

session_start();

if( !isset( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) || (time() - $_SESSION['login_time']) > 60) /*session expires after 1 minute*/
{
    //logout code such as session unset, destroy;

    header("Location:login.php");

}
else
{
    //page  contents if any

}
?>
```

gc_maxlifetime has it's own issues. So I don't want to implement it. Found another using ajax with php, but want to make sure is there any other possible. please confirm a way to implement this.

Comment: You can set the session to expire in x minutes... every time the page is loaded. That way, if they are inactive for x minutes, it will expire the session.

Comment: As my title says i don't want inactive expire or expire on page load. I want auto expire in x minutes.

Comment: Ok I will explain my requirement clearly. I want to give any user say 5 minutes of time. After 5 minutes from his login time, the user should be logged out automatically and redirected to login page irrespective of being he is active or inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, PHP only executes in response to HTTP requests, and therefore sessions are not cleaned until a request arrives. When and how this is done is configured using the [session configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) parameters.

While you cannot directly run the session management code, you can cause it to run by configuring the parameters and then simulating a request via `cron` or a similar tool. Ping your server every minute (or whatever) with an unpublished URL request that sets `session.gc_probability` to 100 and then starts a session. This will cause the session management code to garbage collect the sessions--which will effectively cleanup any timed out sessions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is this to clean up expired sessions (timed out sessions)? My requirement is to log out user from an active session after specified minutes without any HTTP request. I understand PHP only executes in response to HTTP requests. I glad to ideas using multiple web technologies.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when the user is "logged out"?

Comment: I don't want to do anything after logging out.Sorry for the confusion if any and thanks so far for your help. My requirement is, I want to give any user say 5 minutes of time. After 5 minutes from his login time, the user should be logged out automatically and redirected to login page irrespective of being he is active or inactive.

Comment: If that is all you want, any of the usual session mechanisms will work. Its just that they do it on demand, instead of "proactively". If you want the user to notice this very near the 5 minute mark, you will need to use page refreshing, or AJAX, or some other Javascript code to keep the browser in-sync with the server state.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I was just wondering if any way to do it proactively. At last I implemented page refresh. Thought AJAX will increase the load on the server. Whether php threading can be implemented to do it proactively?

Comment: That is what my suggestion/answer was trying to address. PHP does not normally have any way to stay active (run) without an HTTP request. You can however use cron to periodically "poke" it.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the time of the session with `session_cache_expire(minutes);`

```
    <?php
    session_cache_expire(30);
    session_start();
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php

Comment: isn't the session_cache_expire is to let the browser store the cache fro  x minutes? I want the server to auto log out an user's session in x minutes without a page load ( not inactivity log out).

Comment: PHP needs a command to run the script. That is, need to load the page. You want to run any database query at logout?

Comment: I understand that PHP needs to be triggered. Is there any way possible to do with combining other technologies such as ajax or anything else is my question. No I don't want to run any database query at logout.

Comment: I've posted another answer, please check if is you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with jQuery.ajax or another ajax you like:

```
<?php
$sessiontime = 60; // 1 minute
$time = $_SESSION['login_time']-time()+$sessiontime;
?>
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/logout-file.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      complete: function(){
         window.location.href = 'login.php';
      }
   });

}, (<?=$time?>*1000));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. I hope this solves my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your welcome! If it does not work let me know so we can help you. If it works, please accept the answer.

Comment: I implemented page refresh as suggested by  Dwayne Towell (above). I didn't get time to implement the above code. Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me. Once I test the code will update here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use meta refresh
eg 30 minutes

META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="1800;URL=../logout.php"